# what event fires when you click on a asp:checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, user-controls

I have something that depending if it is clicked or unclicked will do something.  The thing is, that i tried to do an onclick and it will not fire.  Is there some other thing that is needed for selecting/unselecting a checkbox?

ASP:

```
<div id = "gridDiv">
    Turn on/off some code: 
    <asp:Checkbox runat="server" name = "gridlock" id = "gridLockAttribute" />
</div>
```

ClientSide:

```
$("#gridLockAttribute").click(function(){
   try{
      alert("test");
   }catch(err){

   }
});
```

It doesnt seem to alert.

Comment: That should be fine as long as you run that javascript inside a $(document).ready(

Comment: Double check that the element exists before registering the click handler (e.g. by wrapping the method in a [dom ready function](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)). You can also try using [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change), though the click should be triggered too.

Comment: you should `console.log(err)` or `alert(err)` in the `catch` block...

Comment: I current have it wrapped in a $(window).load(function(){...  WHich pretty much does the same thing.

Comment: it doesnt hit the breakpoints to get to the code, it wasnt registering a "click" in my definition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASP.NET may be name-mangling your ID if the control is within another control, so things like `$("#gridLockAttribute")` won't work. You have to use either:

```
$("#<%= gridLockAttribute.ClientID %>")
```

Or:

```
$('[id$=gridLockAttribute]')
```

I'd prefer the first method.

Furthermore, if you are trying to get the checkbox to cause a postback automatically, you'll need to set the `AutoPostBack` attribute on the checkbox to `True`.

Comment: i am not trying to cause a postback, but i will check to see if this works.

Comment: Don't forget also that you can set a breakpoint in your favorite JavaScript debugger to see if the element is being name-mangled.

Comment: This seems to have fixed the issue....  Now, i can hit the code.  I just need to make it so it does something like if(this is selected) {...}else{...}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/check-checkbox-checked-property-using-jquery